# activating virtualenv and envdir in a bash script

Tags: python, bash, docker, virtualenv

I created a dockerfile that installs **virtualenv** and **virtualenvwrapper** for a **flask** app that runs on **python3**.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-dev \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip && apt-get install unzip

# virtualenv stuff
RUN mkdir -p /opt/virtualenvs

ENV WORKON_HOME /opt/virtualenvs

ENV VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON /usr/bin/python3

# install pip stuff
RUN pip3 install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper



RUN /bin/bash -c "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh \
                  && mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 foobar \
                  && workon foobar \
                  && add2virtualenv /apps/foobar \
                  && echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> /etc/bash.bashrc \
                  && pip3 install -r foobar/requirements.txt"
```

Then in my bash script I do this:

```
echo Starting Gunicorn
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon foobar
envdir /apps/foobar/.envdir gunicorn -w 2 -b 127.0.0.1:5000 dispatch:app --reload
```

But the response that I get is that "envdir" can't be found - which means that is wasn't installed. I don't know how is that possible since it should have been installed through the requirements.txt?

So there must be something that I'm doing wrong, but I just don't know what :)

Tnx,
Tom

**update**:

the problem seems to be that when I access the running container and activate the virtualenvironment of foobar, the stuff from requirements.txt is not installed? But it should be as it runs in the docker RUN command.

Comment: Virtualenvwrapper sourcing line is not properly added to your `.bashrc` in the container. In the penultimate line, `&& echo "source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh" >> /etc/bash.bashrc`, use single quotes instead of the double ones.

Comment: cool tnx, missed that one!